# Combining polygons to make a similar one

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, polygons

One can combine two identical rectangles to form a larger rectangle which is a scaled version of the smaller pieces -- this is the case for two A5 pages combining to A4 page.

Are there any other polygons with that property? What if we allow disconnected "puzzles"?

Comment: Another example is 45-45-90 triangle

Comment: Depends on the exact definition of the property, I guess... You can combine 4 identical triangles to form a larger triangle similar to them all. Also works for 4 identical rectangles.

Comment: Generally, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rep-tile

Comment: It appears these are other 'simple' ones
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/184668/rep-tiles-of-order-2